# Expectation expansion query

Tags: bayesian, estimation, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to do a proof.

Define the best Bayesian estimator by $\theta^B=E(\theta|x)$. Prove that for another estimator $\gamma$ of $\theta$, we have $MSE(\theta^B)\leq$$MSE(\gamma)$.

Proof: $E((\gamma-\theta)^2)=E(((\gamma-\theta^B)+(\theta^B-\theta))^2)$. In my book, they now expand out but instead of the cross term which I would expect, namely $2E[(\gamma-\theta^B)(\theta^B-\theta)]$, they get
$2E[(\gamma-\theta^B)$$E(\theta^B-\theta|X)]$.

How do they get this? I though may be they were using the tower law $E(E[X|Y])=X$ but that doesn't seem to quite fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tower law (also known as the law of iterated expectation) is stated slightly wrong in your question, it should be $E(E[X|Y]) = E(X)$ (note that the left hand side is an expected value, which is a constant, and thus the right hand side must also be a constant instead of a random variable).

By applying the tower law to the term you are wondering about, we get
\begin{equation}
2E[(\gamma - \theta^B)(\theta^B - \theta)]= 2E[E[(\gamma - \theta^B)(\theta^B - \theta) \mid X]].
\end{equation}
The estimators $\gamma$ and $\theta^B$ are deterministic functions of $X$. Thus, also $(\gamma- \theta^B)$ is a deterministic function of $X$ and can be moved outside the inner expectation. Hence, the expression equals
\begin{equation}
 2E[(\gamma - \theta^B)E[(\theta^B - \theta) \mid X]].
\end{equation}